# How to get unique elements after combining two arrays in typescript?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

For example, given two arrays (numbers/alpha-numeric elements):

```
const a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const a2 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
```

I want to get something like:

```
a3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9];
```

where it does not matter if either a1, or a2 get destroyed/ manipulated in the process. I found the following three methods:

1.

```
const a3 = [...new Set([...a1, ...a2])];
```

2. 

```
const a3 = [...a1, ...a2].filter((element, index, arr) => {
    return index === arr.indexOf(element);
});
```

3. 

```
a2.forEach((element) => {
        if (!a1.includes(element)) {
            a1.push(element);
        }
    });
```

Which one among these, or any other method, is the best practice to be followed and/or is more efficient?

Comment: Your first approach is significantly faster than your other two approaches. `indexOf` and `includes` unnecessarily loop through the list.

Comment: @Aplet123 it would seem so, do you know how does a set eliminates the duplicate elements, I'd say it makes use of some modification of the 2nd method, but I am not sure.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: This feels like an opinion question... are the arrays *huge* and/or are you combining two arrays *many many times*?  If so then something like a `Set` or other hash map will be more performant.  If not then any solution that is readable and clear is fine.  Is there such a thing as "best practice" for this aside from opinion? Also see [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @jcalz This block is a part of an API that gets called a lot with different element values for each arrays. I was just wondering if there was any major performance difference between either of these approaches because of the amount of calls

Comment: So why don't you measure the performance for your use case?

Comment: NB/ the third version doesn't produce a new array, which makes the comparison less relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Set has a better time complexity. So that means that you can find an array size such that when the input arrays have at least that size, that Set-solution will outperform the other two.

I have here designed a simple test script, which will try to find the array size above which the Set-based solution is faster. As there are many factors that determine the actual speed of execution (the JS engine, the runtime optimiser, the garbage collector, other processes, ...), the result is not to be taken as an exact figure... just as an indication. Also try in different browsers.

I have made a few choices (which you can of course change to your liking):

- The two input arrays are equal in size, and have small integer numbers
- The first array has numbers from 0 to *n*-1, where *n* is its size.
- The second input array has only multiples of 5, ranging from 0 to 5(*n*-1)
- Both arrays are shuffled
- I selected the Set-based solution, and a variant of the includes-based solution.
- The test counts the number of times the chosen algorithm can do the job on those arrays within 500 milliseconds.
- These two counts are compared to decide which of the two is faster.

The size of the arrays is dynamically adapted, so to find the "ideal" size where both counts are about the same.

Here is the snippet:

```js
// Utility functions:
function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
}

const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

function hasSetBetterPerformance(length) {
    console.log("Measuring performance for arrays with length " + length + "...");
    
    // As test material we create 2 equal sized, numerical arrays.
    //   These arrays have no duplicates.
    //   The second one has 20% of its values occuring also 
    //   in the first, while the other 80% do not occur in the first.
    let arr1 = shuffle(Array.from({length}, (_, i) => i));
    let arr2 = shuffle(Array.from({length}, (_, i) => i * 5)); // 1 in 5 is a duplicate   
    let stop, res, balance = 0;

    // Execute the Set-based solution during 500 milliseconds
    stop = performance.now() + 500;
    while (performance.now() < stop) {
        res = [...new Set([...arr1, ...arr2])];
        balance++;
    }
    
    res = [];
    
    // Execute the includes-based solution during 500 milliseconds
    stop = performance.now() + 500;
    while (performance.now() < stop) {
        res = [...arr1]; // To be fair, we must create a new array
        for (let element of arr2) {
            if (!arr1.includes(element)) res.push(element);
        }
        balance--;
    }
    
    return balance >= 0;
}


async function findTurningPoint() {
    let high = 2;

    // Find size for which Set algorithm is faster
    while (!hasSetBetterPerformance(high)) {
        high *= 2;
        await delay(10);
    }
    // Narrow down, using binary search...
    let low = high / 2;
    while (low < high) {
        let mid = Math.floor((low + high) / 2);
        if (hasSetBetterPerformance(mid)) {
            high = mid;
        } else {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        await delay(10);
    }
    console.log("Turning point after which Set is faster: arrays with length >=", low);
    return low;
}

findTurningPoint();
```

Different runs may give different results, but on my PC, FireFox and Chrome report a size somewhere between 50 and 90.

So this can give you an indication whether to go for the Set solution, depending on the actual array sizes you are working with.

Be careful: the performance may differ when the array values have a different type (floats, strings, ...), or a different probability of having duplicates, or when the arrays do not have the same size. All that should be taken into account.